# How to create this custom view

Tags: java, android, windows, view, microsoft-metro

As seen in the picture shown below

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to make a view like this but I can't seem to figure out the logic for navigating between the tabs. I want to make this possible on android. I know that it can be done because this is a picture from UberMusic, which is an app available for Android. I wanna create a view just like this one. Is there anyone that can help me get started? I want it to replicate the new Metro Windows Pivot Control. Thanks for anyone that can help!

Comment: why to take tab instead you can use Textview itself using Selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Expandable List Adapter for each tab

Comment: but how would i implement the infinite scrolling and swipe from left to right and vice versa?

Comment: In xml just use <ScrollView> and inside that <HorizontalScrollView>., then it will work for both.